# How can nautilus-open-terminal, the Nautilus context menu item, be installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, nautilus, 16.04

I have attempted to use `apt-get` to install it, but I can't seem to find it:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal-here
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works according to the @d3pd:

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-dev libnautilus-extension-dev intltool
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/133550689/nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz‌
tar -xvf nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz
cd nautilus-open-terminal-0.20
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your suggestions. This doesn't appear to be working for me on 16.04. It can't seem to find the package.

Comment: Try Synaptic to locate the required package: sudo apt install synaptic

Comment: Also, try downloading "nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz" from this location-  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/0.20-1  Extract,  Make and install the file. See if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The following procedure worked: `sudo apt-get install libgconf2-dev libnautilus-extension-dev; wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/133550689/nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz; tar -xvf nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz; cd nautilus-open-terminal-0.20/; ./configure; make; sudo make install`. Thanks! (Also, feel free to add this to your solution.)

Comment: The correct link is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/nautilus-open-terminal_0.20.orig.tar.xz

Comment: Note, the `intltool` package is required, otherwise `./configure` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in the similar situation on Xubuntu 16.04. After installing nautilus run:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions gnome-terminal && nautilus -q
```